# Export iOS Health data daily

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, health.app

Is there a way to export iOS Health data daily?

I know about the in-app export option, but is there a way to automatize this process. Could be an app as well.

Probably something like [QS Access](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qs-access/id920297614?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6), but this tool is lacking automatic export as well.

A daily email export would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Quantified Self](http://quantifiedself.com/) have created [QS Access](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/qs-access/id920297614?mt=8), an app that lets you access your HealthKit data in a table you can explore in Excel or Numbers.

This free app is at present the best way to export and analyze the data Health collects. Install the app, give it the permissions it needs, select the data you want to export and it will gather the results and present them in a CSV spreadsheet you can share.

Comment: The very same app was mentioned in the question as well. And this is quite the same that the native apps export gives me. What I need is a periodically automatic export mechanism.

Comment: You didn't mention any app until my answer was given. After that you edited your question to mention the app. If this is sort of cheating to get some points, you will be reported.
As for automatic export, check https://ifttt.com tool.
Cheers.

Comment: Feel free to check that this edit was made 2 hours ago, while your answer was given 1 hour ago, so no point to argue on that :) Thanks for ifttt, though. Going to figure if that works later today!

Comment: Seems like IFTTT doens't connect to HealthKit nor QA Acess... Any other ideas? @ranklord

Comment: Did you give authority to QS Access to access the Health app data? @SilverRingvee

Comment: Yes, the table creation is working well, now I am interested in automating the process, to send the table via email, once a day, for example @ranklord

Comment: Looks like there is currently no completely automatic way of exporting health data daily.